# How to override the SaveChangesAsync of any DbContext globaly?

Tags: c#, .net, ef-core-2.0

I want to override the

```
public virtual Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
```

of any `DbContext` in my solution globaly and change it to

```
public virtual Task<MyDatabaseReturnModel> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do and where would that `MyDatabaseReturnModel` come from? `SaveChanges` is supposed to save changes, not perform extra queries.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have a problem X and assume Y is the solution. When that doesn't work you ask about Y, not the actual problem X. What is the *actual* problem you want to solve?

Comment: Its not a XY problem, thank you.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I want to add a try / catch around the savechangesasync, log the error into a special file and enrich the result from a simple int to a succeded (bool), error message (string), and resultset (int)

Comment: So it *is* an XY problem. You want to log exceptions. That's the job of your *logging library*, not Entity Framework. You can configure EF Core to log its messages to your logging provider already, in fact, if you use .NET Core's logging infrastructure [that may work already](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging)

Comment: Apart from that, exceptions are like a blown fuse. You can't just log them and forget about them. They should be handled at the highest level where that makes sense. If saving to the database fails, probably *everything* the user did up to that point should also fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is that possible?

No. You can't change the *signature* of a method by overriding it. You can only change the *implementation*. The `SaveChangesAsync` method must still return a `Task<int>` or `int`. This is how it is defined.